# How to change marker and color in matplotlib for a specific column value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data file including 3 columns. The first 2 columns represent coordinates, the third one is a string value like 'foo', 'bar' or 'ter'.

I would like to display with python's matplotlib based on this label, different marker and color. Example:

- foo => red circle
- bar => green triangle
- ter => black square

What I did till now is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coordData = np.genfromtxt("mydata.csv", usecols=(0,1), delimiter=",", dtype=None)
coordLabels = np.genfromtxt("mydata.csv", usecols=2, delimiter=",", dtype=None)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(coordData[:, 0], coordData[:, 1], c="r", marker="o") 
plt.show()
```

How can I switch marker and color based on the `coordLabels` values?

**SOLUTION**

Based on the suggestion I made some changes:

```
coordData = np.genfromtxt("mydata.csv", usecols=(0, 1), delimiter=",", dtype=None)
coordLabels = np.genfromtxt("mydata.csv", usecols=2, delimiter=",", dtype=None)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

uniqueVals = np.unique(coordLabels)

markers = ['^', 'o', '*']
colors = { '^' : 'r',
           'o' : 'b',
           '*' : 'g'}

for marker, val in zip(markers, uniqueVals):
    toUse = coordLabels == val
    ax.scatter(coordData[toUse,0], coordData[toUse,1], c = colors[marker], marker=marker)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the color to be dependent upon the label in `coordLabels`, you want to set the color equal to *that* variable instead of `'r'` like you have.

```
ax.scatter(coordData[:, 0], coordData[:, 1], c=coordLabels, marker="o")
```

If you want different *markers* for each of the plots, you will need to create multiple scatter plots (one for each value in `coordLabels`

```
uniqueVals = ['foo', 'bar', 'ter']

# Create your own list of markers here (needs to be the same size as `uniqueVals`)
markers = ['o', '^', 's']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for color, marker, val in zip(colors, markers, uniqueVals):
    toUse = coordLabels == val
    ax.scatter(coordData[toUse,0], coordData[toUse,1], c=color, marker=marker)
```

Comment: With some changes I have adapted your suggestion. Thank you.